# is delegate the fastest way of binding?

Tags: jquery, performance

Could someone explain why delegate seems faster than alias binding or on().

This is a test case:

[jsPerf](http://jsperf.com/test-on-click-delegate)

```
$('p').on('click',$.noop); //80% slower

$('p').click($.noop); //84% slower

$(document).delegate("p", "click",$.noop); //fastest
```

Checking jquery source, it seems like before binding any event, jquery check for delegates.

Is it a correct statement or is there anything else?

Comment: Try setting `delegate` on something you have to look up.

Comment: Since `delegate()` calls `on()` (they're equivalent except for the order of arguments) there's no way it can be more efficient.

Comment: Note that the problem isn't in looking for the `p` elements : http://jsperf.com/test-on-click-delegate/2

Comment: *"it seems like before triggering any event"* what would triggering an event have to do with this? you aren't triggering events here, just binding.

Comment: @KevinB ya sorry for the misspelling

Comment: Comparing `$(document).on("click", "p", $.noop);` and `$(document).delegate("p", "click", $.noop);` are roughly the same. I don't see any difference.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The error you made was to think there was only one p element.

I added another test, with only `console.log($('p').length);` and it showed that there was 7 p visible from the test, whose visibility was obviously not limited to the HTML you built in the preparation code.

This means that the two first functions had to do 7 more bindings.

Answer (score 5):

Both `delegate()` and `bind()` simply call `on()`. Here's an excerpt from the jQuery 1.9.0 source:

```
bind: function( types, data, fn ) {
    return this.on( types, null, data, fn );
},
delegate: function( selector, types, data, fn ) {
    return this.on( types, selector, data, fn );
},
```

So `on()` should be slightly faster than the other two functions, since it's one less function call. The actual invocation of the handler should be identical no matter which way it was bound.

But make sure you're comparing apples with apples. If you give a `selector` argument to `delegate` or `bind`, invoking the handler will be slower because it has to check whether the target satisfies the selector.

The reason for your benchmark result is because

```
$("p").on('click',$.noop);
```

is equivalent to something like:

```
$("p").each(function() {
    $(this).on('click', $.noop);
});
```

It has to find all the matching elements and bind a handler to them. The `delegate()` call only has to bind a handler to one element (the document); instead of finding all the elements at binding time, at the time the event occurs it does something like:

```
if ($(event.target).is("p")) { ... }
```

The use of `on()` that's equivalent to `delegate()` would be:

```
$(document).on('click', 'p', $.noop);
```

When you delegate from a large element like `document`, you're invoking the internal handler every time you click anywhere in the document, wasting time testing if you're over a `p`. This is why you should try to limit the scope of the element used in `delegate` to the smallest static element that contains all the dynamic elements you want to delegate to.

Comment: Thx for explanation. Following dystroy's answer, i get it now.

Answer (score 5):

delegate is only faster because you don't have to look up any elements, if you use a selector instead of an elements delegate will be the slowest

```
<div>
<p>test</p>
</div>


$('p').on('click',$.noop);
$('p').click($.noop);
$('div').delegate("p", "click",$.noop);
```

http://jsperf.com/test-on-click-delegate/3